# JNI multidimensional array as return value

Tags: c++, java, jni

I have some C++ code that I wrote to generate voxel terrain and would like to access it in JAVA. you pass it three integers; the seed and the coordinates of the chunk that it is generating (represented as `int x` and `int y`). It returns to you a 3D array of integers representing the value of each block in that chunk. In java I have:

`private native static int [ ][ ][ ] genTerrain ( int seed , int x , int y );`

And in the generated header I have:

```
#ifndef _Included_co_lambdas_koc_server_Terrain
#define _Included_co_lambdas_koc_server_Terrain
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     co_lambdas_koc_server_Terrain
 * Method:    genTerrain
 * Signature: (III)[[[I
 */
JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_co_lambdas_koc_server_Terrain_genTerrain
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jint, jint, jint);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

And for the Class file I have tried:

```
JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL
Java_co_lambdas_koc_server_Terrain_genTerrain ( JNIEnv * env , jclass , jint seed , jint xCord , jint yCord )
{
    jclass intClass = env->FindClass("[I");

    jintArray x = env->NewIntArray ( 32 ) ;
    jintArray y = env->NewIntArray ( 32 ) ;
    jintArray z = env->NewIntArray ( 512 ) ;

    jobjectArray terrain = env->NewObjectArray(3, intClass, NULL);
    env->SetObjectArrayElement(terrain, 0, x);
    env->SetObjectArrayElement(terrain, 1, y);
    env->SetObjectArrayElement(terrain, 2, z);

    return ( terrain ) ;
}
```

Of-course this may be completely invalid as I have found little JNI documentation and haven't been able to understand much of what I have read. Could anyone show me how to generate a 3D JAVA int array (`jint[][][]`) in C++ through JNI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit inconvenient: You have to create each array manually, along each dimension:

- Create an object array with size `sizeX`, with element type `[[I` (a **2D** `int` array)
- At each entry of this array:

  - Create an object array, with size `sizeY`, with element type `[I` (a **1D** `int` array)
  - At each entry of this array:

    - Create an int array, with size `sizeZ`

Here is an example:

```
#include "TestNativeArray3D.h"

JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_TestNativeArray3D_genTerrain
    (JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jint seed, jint xCoord, jint yCoord)
{
    jclass intArray1DClass = env->FindClass("[I");
    jclass intArray2DClass = env->FindClass("[[I");

    jint sizeX = 4;
    jint sizeY = 5;
    jint sizeZ = 6;

    jobjectArray array3D = env->NewObjectArray(
        sizeX, intArray2DClass, NULL);
    for (jint x = 0; x < sizeX; x++)
    {
        jobjectArray array2D = env->NewObjectArray(
            sizeY, intArray1DClass, NULL);
        for (jint y = 0; y < sizeY; y++)
        {
            jintArray array1D = env->NewIntArray(sizeZ);
            env->SetObjectArrayElement(array2D, y, array1D);
        }
        env->SetObjectArrayElement(array3D, x, array2D);
    }
    return array3D;
}
```

(Note: In "real" code, you should *diligently* check for error conditions, and exit the method as soon as possible. For example, the allocations may fail due to an `OutOfMemoryError`, and will return `NULL` in this case).

> EDIT In response to the comment

Actually *accessing* or *filling* the innermost arrays is again a different story. There are several functions and approaches for this:

- [GetIntArrayRegion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#Get_PrimitiveType_ArrayRegion_routines) and [SetIntArrayRegion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#Set_PrimitiveType_ArrayRegion_routines), as the names suggest, are intended for reading/writing parts (regions) of an array to/from a data buffer that was allocated separately
- [GetIntArrayElements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#Get_PrimitiveType_ArrayElements_routines) and [ReleaseIntArrayElements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#Release_PrimitiveType_ArrayElements_routines): The `Get` function tries to obtain a *pointer* to the actual array contents, that can then be accessed and modified, and later be "committed" back to the array by calling the `Release` function. (See the documentation about the cases where it might not return a pointer, but a *copy* of the data instead!)
- [GetPrimitiveArrayCritical/ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#GetPrimitiveArrayCritical_ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical): This also tries to obtain a pointer to the array contents, but ... it tries even harder ;-) Again, refer to the documentation for details (it may disable garbage collection, for example, so should be used with some care)

So depending on how the actual process of filling the arrays looks like, you'd employ different techniques.

Which of the first functions (`Get*ArrayElements` vs. `Get*ArrayRegion`) is faster heavily depends on the *size* of the region that you're interested in. If you have an array with 10000 elements, but only want to read/write a few elements, the `...Region` based functions are likely to be faster. If you have to access the whole array anyhow, the `...Elements` based functions should be more appropriate. But admittedly, I have not (yet) made detailed, dedicated performance comparisons here (these would depend on *many* factors - array size, region size, JVM version, ...). The `...Critical` method is likely to be the fastest for nearly all cases, but should only be used when there is a dedicated point where you can quickly acquire+use+release the data, and don't have any other JNI calls in between.

---

Based on your description, it sounds like you could fill the arrays **during** their creation (assuming that you create the native data before actually creating the Java arrays). You don't have many choices in terms of granularity: The innermost `int[]` arrays are the largest possible block that you can use here. So you could do something like this after creating the innermost `array1D`:

```
jint *a = (jint*)env->GetPrimitiveArrayCritical(array1D, NULL);

// Use `a` here (But don't do more than just accessing the 
// array - particularly, don't to any time-consuming 
// computations, and don't call other JNI functions!)
for (jint z = 0; z < sizeZ; z++)
{
    a[z] = z; // Fill with actual (pre-computed) data
}
env->ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical(array1D, a, NULL);
```

---

A general hint: As you might have noticed, the handling of 3D arrays is not something that flows easily from your fingertips in JNI. Many libraries that are concerned with handling large data blocks try to "flatten" multidimensional arrays into 1D array. This is something you should consider as well, if it is possible based on your existing C implementation and depending on how the data will be used on the Java side.

<sub>(BTW: I hope you're not doing this in C for the sake of performance. Porting the terrain generation code to Java might be a viable option, too ;-))</sub>

Comment: I have conformed this compiles and works but how do I set a variable I suppose `env->SetObjectArrayElement(array3D,INDEX , 4);` But what would I put for index it wouldn't be as simple as a single dimension array.

Comment: @Pointlight One could write a wall of text about this. And I just did this ;-) See the edit.

Comment: nope just doing it in c++ because I haven't completed the terrain engine for the client side (c++) and it makes more sense to reuse the code than to simultaneously program a c++ and java version concurrently

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> filter_boxes;

jclass intArray1DClass = env->FindClass("[I");
jclass intArray2DClass = env->FindClass("[[I");

jint sizeX = filter_boxes.size();
jint sizeY = 4;
jint sizeZ = 2;

jobjectArray  array3D = env->NewObjectArray(sizeX, intArray2DClass, NULL);
for (jint x = 0; x < sizeX; x++)
{
    jobjectArray array2D = env->NewObjectArray(sizeY, intArray1DClass, NULL);
    for (jint y = 0; y < sizeY; y++)
    {
        jintArray array1D = env->NewIntArray(sizeZ);
         jint *buf = new jint[2];
         for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
             buf[i] = (jint) filter_boxes[x][y][i];
         }
        env->SetIntArrayRegion(array1D, 0, 2, buf);
        env->SetObjectArrayElement(array2D, y, array1D);
        delete[] buf;
    }
    env->SetObjectArrayElement(array3D, x, array2D);
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanations to your answer. Even though "code is self-documenting" it will help others to understand your code much faster if you explain the relevant parts.